# Can a wok be used with home gas stoves?

Tags: wok

I'm getting my friends a wok as a wedding gift and I'm concerned that it will be unusable on their ordinary gas stove.

Can woks be used with everyday gas stoves? If not, what is the extra equipment needed to use a wok at home?

Comment: Welcome -- does the suggested existing question answer your question? If not, please [edit] and let us know what additional details you need. (Hope your friends enjoy their wok!)